# mysql day report query

Tags: mysql

The query below gives me a report of items that are out for an equipment rental company.  this is a super complicated query that takes almost 20 seconds to run.  This is obviously not the correct way to get the data that I'm looking for.   I build this query from PHP and add in the start date of 02-01-2011 and the end date of 03-01-2011, the product code (p_code = 1) and product pool (i_pool =1).  Those 4 pieces of information are passed to a PHP function and injected into the following sql to return the report I need for a calendar control displaying how many items are out. My question is:  Is there any way to simplify or do this better, or run more efficiently, using better joins or a better way to display the individual days.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT reportdays.reportday, count(*)
FROM 
(SELECT '2011-02-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY reportday
FROM
 (SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) d,
 (SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 
    UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40) m 
WHERE '2011-02-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY  <  '2011-03-01'
ORDER BY a + b) as reportdays
 JOIN rental_inv as line 
    ON DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(line.ri_delivery_dte)) <= reportdays.reportday
  AND  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(line.ri_pickup_dte)) >= reportdays.reportday
 LEFT OUTER JOIN rental_in as rent on line.ri_num = rent.ri_num
 LEFT OUTER JOIN rental_cancels cancelled on rent.ri_num = cancelled.ri_num
 LEFT OUTER JOIN inv inventory on line.i_num = inventory.i_num
 LEFT OUTER JOIN product ON inventory.p_code = product.p_code
 WHERE rent.ri_extend = 0      -- disregard extended rentals
  AND cancelled.ri_num is null -- disregard cancelled rentals
  AND inventory.p_code = 1
  AND inventory.i_pool = 1

 GROUP BY reportdays.reportday
```

If there is any other information needed, let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: I'm doing a horrible job of explaining this.  I need to revamp this question in an hour or so.

Comment: ri_delievery_dte and ri_pickup_dte are int fields holding timestamps, why the database designer used timestamps to represent dates I do not know.  I figure a date field would have been better.  if ri_extend has a value then that means that the order has been replaced by a new order, if the order is listed in the rental_cancels table, then the order had been cancelled, all this seems like a dumb way to model the data, but I didn't design this structure or database, it's been around for 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT DATE(ri_delivery) as day,
       count(*) as itemsout,
  FROM rental_inv
GROUP BY day;
```

I'm not sure if you need this or a different thing.

```
  SELECT dates.day, count (*)
    FROM rental_inv line
         INNER JOIN (SELECT DATE(ri_delivery_dte) as day FROM rental_inv  
                      WHERE ri_delivery_dte >= '2011/02/01' 
                        AND ri_delivery_dte <= '2011/02/28' 
                     GROUP BY day
                     UNION 
                     SELECT DATE(ri_pickup_dte) as day FROM rental_inv 
                      WHERE ri_pickup_dte >= '2011/02/01' 
                        AND ri_pickup_dte <= '2011/02/28'
                    GROUP BY day) dates
                 ON line.ri_delivery_dte <= dates.day and line.ri_pickup_dte >= dates.day
          LEFT JOIN rental_cancels canc on line.ri_num =  canc.ri_num 
          LEFT JOIN rental_in rent on line.ri_num = rent.ri_num
    WHERE  canc.ri_num is  null
       AND rent.ri_extend = 0
 GROUP BY dates.day
```

Comment: a little more complicated that than, it has to be the number of items between delivery day and pickup day, and return in the same format with the first column being the reportday, and the second column being the quantity, given the month of February, 2011, there should be 28 rows, for each of the days in february.

Comment: @stephenbayer. I'm not very sure what do you need and what are the new table that you use on the new query.

Comment: I know, i explained it horribly.  I've got the working query, but it is not done very well and takes 18.84 seconds right now to run.  which is rather unacceptable. but worked for the moment while I showed the data to the client.  I'm redoing my question now.

Answer (score 0):

to find all days:

SELECT DATE(IFNULL(ri_delivery,ri_pickup)) AS `date` FROM rental_inv AS dateindex WHERE  [YEAR-MONTH-1] <= ri_delivery <= LAST_DAY([YEAR-MONTH-1]) OR   [YEAR-MONTH-1] <= ri_pickup <= LAST_DAY([YEAR-MONTH-1]) GROUP BY `date` HAVING NOT ISNULL(`date`)

to find items out

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM rental_inv  WHERE ri_pickup = [DATE];
to find items in

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM rental_inv  WHERE ri_delivery = [DATE];
to find balance

SELECT COUNT(out.id) - COUNT(in.id)  FROM rental_inv AS out INNER JOIN rental_inv AS in
ON DATE(out.ri_pickup) = DATE(in.ri_delivery) WHERE  out.ri_pickup = [DATE] OR in.ri_delivery = [DATE]

You probably can join up everything but since its procedure its more clear;

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would be the exact answer to your problem but I would do something like this I guess. (I didn't use any SQL editor so u need to check syntax I guess)

```
SELECT 
    reportdays.d3 as d, 
    ( COALESCE(outgoing.c1,0) - COALESCE(incoming.c2,0) ) as c
FROM
-- get report dates 
(
    SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(COALESCE(l3.ri_delivery_dte, l3.ri_pickup_dte)) d3
    FROM rental_inv l3
    WHERE
        (l3.ri_delivery_dte >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01') 
            AND l3.ri_delivery_dte < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01'))
        OR (l3.ri_pickup_dte >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01') 
            AND l3.ri_pickup_dte < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01'))
    GROUP BY d3
) as reportdays
-- get outgoing
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(l1.ri_delivery_dte)) as d1, count(*) as c1
    FROM rental_inv l1
    LEFT JOIN rental_cancels canc1 on l.ri_num =  canc1.ri_num 
    LEFT JOIN rental_in rent1 on l.ri_num = rent1.ri_num
    WHERE
       l1.ri_delivery_dte >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01')
       AND l1.ri_delivery_dte < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')
       AND  canc1.ri_num is  null
       AND rent1.ri_extend = 0
    GROUP BY d1
) as outgoing ON reportdays.d3 = outgoing.d1
-- get incoming
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(l2.ri_pickup_dte)) as d2, count(*) as c2
    FROM rental_inv l2
    LEFT JOIN rental_cancels canc2 on l2.ri_num =  canc2.ri_num 
    LEFT JOIN rental_in rent2 on l2.ri_num = rent2.ri_num
    WHERE
       l2.ri_pickup_dte >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-02-01')
       AND l2.ri_pickup_dte < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-03-01')
       AND  canc2.ri_num is  null
       AND rent2.ri_extend = 0
    GROUP BY d2
) as incoming ON reportdays.d3 = incoming.d2
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'm trying to get that to work, and I can't right now, but I'll paste it into a SQL management window and work on it when I get home, I'm getting a mysql error #1064 near 'd FROM rental_inv line WHERE (ri_delivery_dt... when I tried to run it, so I'm going to try to parse that out and get it to work and see if this will help.

Comment: I added more alias to avoid overlapping. hope it works. and be sure you have index on both date fields.